# Binding multiple value sets to a single extension element

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm wondering if there is a way to bind multiple value sets to a single extension element in fhir.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<StructureDefinition xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  ...
  <snapshot>
    ...
    <element>
      <path value="Extension.valueCode"/>
      ...
      <type>
        <code value="code"/>
      </type>
      <binding>
        <strength value="required"/>
        <valueSetUri value="http://stelar.org/valueSet/const-yesNo"/>
      </binding>
      <binding>
        <strength value="required"/>
        <valueSetUri value="http://stelar.org/valueSet/missingData"/>
      </binding>
    </element>
    ...
  </snapshot>
  ...
</StructureDefinition>
```

My reason for wanting to bind multiple is that I'm porting data over from a legacy system in which coded values can either come from a value set which represents collected data, or a separate value set which represents missing data.  The reason for the split is that sometimes more is known about why the data is missing.

I don't really want to go an create a composite value set for every combination of the missing value set, and the various other value sets if possible, as this will really minimise the reuseability of the value domains.

I'm not sure if I'm just getting my syntax wrong, but I can't find any mention of multiple bindings in the documentation, and which I upload the file in the above (or below format) to simplifier, it only renders one bound domain, which makes me think it is just accepting the last child.

```
  <binding>
    <strength value="required"/>
    <valueSetUri value="http://stelar.org/valueSet/const-yesNo"/>
    <valueSetUri value="http://stelar.org/valueSet/missingData"/>
  </binding>
```

Is there a way to bind multiple value sets?  Is there a better way of handling missing data in fhir?

Answer (score 1):

See http://build.fhir.org/elementdefinition-definitions.html#ElementDefinition.binding - binding can only appear once. Creating multiple bindings has a number of practical consequences, so the expectation is that you'll define a single value set that imports the other 2 value sets you might include. Note that you could create a contained value set in the structure definition that imports the two actual value sets, since it has no real existence or meaning outside the structure definition

We are discussing use cases for multiple bindings right now - but it's complicated. If there's more than one binding, is that 'and' or 'or'?